# Why the scrapy-redis not work?

Tags: python, redis, scrapy, web-crawler

I download the scrapy-redis from github and run it following the instruction but it failed and give this error:

```
2013-01-04 17:38:50+0800 [-] ERROR: Unhandled error in Deferred:
2013-01-04 17:38:50+0800 [-] Unhandled Error
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Scrapy-0.16.3-py2.7.egg/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 138, in _run_command
            cmd.run(args, opts)
          File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Scrapy-0.16.3-py2.7.egg/scrapy/commands/crawl.py", line 44, in run
            self.crawler.crawl(spider)
          File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Scrapy-0.16.3-py2.7.egg/scrapy/crawler.py", line 47, in crawl
            return self.engine.open_spider(spider, requests)
          File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Twisted-12.2.0-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1187, in unwindGenerator
            return _inlineCallbacks(None, gen, Deferred())
        --- <exception caught here> ---
          File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Twisted-12.2.0-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1045, in _inlineCallbacks
            result = g.send(result)
          File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Scrapy-0.16.3-py2.7.egg/scrapy/core/engine.py", line 218, in open_spider
            scheduler = self.scheduler_cls.from_crawler(self.crawler)
        exceptions.AttributeError: type object 'Scheduler' has no attribute 'from_crawler'
```

How to handle this?Thanks.

Comment: What version of `redis-py` do you have? It could be too new or too old for either your `scrapy-redis` or your `twisted`…

Comment: I tried redis-py 2.4.9 but the error still occurs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is that scrapy-redis was written a year ago using scrapy 0.13. The current version of scrapy is 0.17 and if you compare the [current source code](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/tree/master/scrapy/core) of scrapy/core/engine.py with a [version from last year](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/cb9c937f50aaeaf67aba3f54cecdf6bb854aabf7/scrapy/core/engine.py), you can see that the line causing the error was added at some point between those two versions (in fact, it was added on [August 21st 2012](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/1e12c92b8f4114b75bac7bed714d2e59e12b701d/scrapy/core/engine.py))

In short, the error is occurring because scrapy-redis is no longer compatible with current versions of scrapy. It might be worth contacting the developer to ask him/her if the project is still active, otherwise it will be necessary to fork the repository and fix it yourself.

Comment: +1. Although there's always the option of installing scrapy-0.13 (and, to be safe, maybe equally old versions of the other prereqs). You don't always need the newest of everything for every project (and if you did, you wouldn't be using Python 2), after all.

Answer (score 1):

Well I made a few changes to the old scrapy-redis to compatible with scrapy 0.17. It is not fully tested. Here is the [code](https://github.com/RushMind/scrapy-redis).